# What is the link that should be provided in appSettings when trying to connect to MS Dynamics 365

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to connect to MS Dynamics 365 CRM and can anyone tell me what should be the value provided in the `appSettings`.

The Value I have given is as follows:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key ="crmserverurl" value="https://server.crm8.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Did you test my answer?

Comment: Yes sir, but it did not work i got it by using <appsettings>

Comment: I didn’t get you. How does appsettings in all small case helped you?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key ="crmserverurl" value="https://testorg.crm8.dynamics.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

I would recommend using `connectionStrings` compared to `appSettings`.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CRM" connectionString="AuthType=Office365;Url=https://testorg.crm8.dynamics.com; Username=testuser@testorg.onmicrosoft.com; Password=MyPassword" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="..." />
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="MyAppSetting" value="..." />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Using this configs, use code below.

```
var urlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

var urlAppSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyAppSetting"];

public void ConnectToMSCRM(string UserName,string Password,string SoapOrgServiceUri)
{
    try
    {
        ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.UserName.UserName = UserName;
        credentials.UserName.Password = Password;
        Uri serviceUri = new Uri(SoapOrgServiceUri);
        OrganizationServiceProxy proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serviceUri, null, credentials, null);
        proxy.EnableProxyTypes();
        _service = (IOrganizationService)proxy;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error while connecting to CRM " + ex.Message);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If you are using this code to connect. Just use "**Organization Service**" from "**Developer Resources**".